# fuse_js_1.default is not a constructor | Fuse.js in Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, constructor, fuse.js

i have a little API in express js with Typescript - Node 14 and i'm using fuse js to search a list of packages in the database. (the file name is server.ts)
This is how the ts code looks:

```
const fuse = new Fuse (list, options)
```

and compiles fine but when i deploy the code in the server show an error

```
... fuse_js_1.default is not a constructor ...
```

so i go to the server.js result file and the code is like this

```
const fuse = new fuse_js_1.default(list, options)
```

if i remove `.default` word, the code looks like this `new fuse_js_1(list, options)` the code runs fine and works!!

Is there a way to force Typescript not to compile this line? or remove the .default automatically? I accept your comments and ideas thanks :)

Sorry, bag english :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, change

```
import Fuse from "fuse.js"
```

to

```
const Fuse = require("fuse.js")
```

:)

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, the fix was to add `"esModuleInterop": true` to `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "esModuleInterop": true,
    },
}
```

Comment: It's right. I checked.